# Keep content inside footer

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, footer

I've been working on a landing page for a client and I've come across a problem when trying to keep my footer_content inside the footer
The all page is responsive but when it comes to the  footer_content he just doesn't work. Right know I styled it back to px instead of % to have some functional work to show but if you guys could help m e make it responsive and block it inside the footer and would really appreciate it.
My code right now is:

```
<div class="foot">
    <div class="foot_content">
    <div class="foot_title">
        <p style="font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">AS NOSSAS FUNCIONALIDADES<p>
        <p style="font-size:12px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; line-height:18px">Para o ajudar a encontrar os seus futuros clientes.<p>
    </div>
    <div class="foot_text_content">
        <div class="foot_text_col_1">
            <img src="img/pub.png" alt="publicidade" />
            <p style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; margin-top:10px">GERIMOS A SUA PUBLICIDADE<p>
            <div style="line-height:16px; margin-top:5px; font-size:14px">
                <p>A nossa equipa de designers está<p>
                <p>sempre pronta para dár resposta às<p>
                <p>suas necessidades criativas.<p>
                <p>Assim que resolvidas poderemos<p>
                <p>ainda publicitá-las no nosso website.<p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="foot_text_col_2">
            <img src="img/negocio.png" alt="negócio" />
            <p style="font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; margin-top:10px">GERAMOS NEGÓCIOS<p>
            <div style="line-height:16px; margin-top:5px; font-size:14px">
                <p>O nosso website funciona como uma<p>
                <p>rampa de lançamento para o seu negócio.<p>
                <p>Através do “SEO” do nosso website,<p>
                <p>garantimos que a sua publicidade<p>
                <p>chegará a todos os seus clientes.<p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="foot_text_col_3">
            <img src="img/success.png" alt="negócio" />
            <p style="font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; margin-top:10px">GARANTIMOS SUCESSO<p>
            <div style="line-height:16px; margin-top:5px; font-size:14px">
                <p>Com todas estas ferramentas que<p>
                <p>referimos, o seu sucesso será<p>
                <p>garantido, resta-lhe apenas fechar<p>
                <p>negócio.<p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="background">
    <img src="img/foot_bg.png" />
</div>
```

and the css is

```
.foot {
    position:absolute;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
    height: 41.5%;
}

.background {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    position:absolute;
}

.background img {
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width:100%;
    min-width:90%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height:41.5%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index:-1;
}

.foot_content {
    width:960px;
    height:258px;
    margin:auto;
    bottom:20px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}

.foot_title {
    width:960px;
    height:34px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}

.foot_text_content {
    width:960px;
    height:193px;
    margin-top:30px;
}

.foot_text_col_1 {
    width:267px;
    height:193px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}

.foot_text_col_2 {
    width:267px;
    height:193px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:absolute;
}

.foot_text_col_3 {
    width:267px;
    height:193px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
}`
```

Thanks in advance

*EDIT* Fiddle link as requested https://jsfiddle.net/wppo1bvo/

Comment: People will more likely be of help if you provide a working example of your code (here or JSFiddle or something else).

Comment: You have invalid markup on your code...you are missing a close div (close div.foot)

Comment: Also, provide your non-working code and not what works for you now. Finally, your HTML isn't valid. There's a missing closing `</div>`  (as @LuisP.A. mentioned) and most closing `</p>` miss the forward slash. Your best friend for this: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: The div.foot closes before the background tag. the error that validator.3w.org gives is because I didn't post the doctype in this example but I have in my code.